# How can widget insert text at certain position?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want my widget to place the text/html at certain position. Could someone help me to understand how can a widget place text

- at very bottom
- at top
- in between paragraph 1 and 2 etc?

working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/kvsfj45w/4/) widget sample where I followed CKEditor 4 [Widget Tutorial](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1.html)

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'simplebox', {
    requires: 'widget',

    icons: 'simplebox',

    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.widgets.add( 'simplebox', {

            button: 'Create a simple box',

            template:
                '<div class="simplebox">' +
                    '<h2 class="simplebox-title">Title</h2>' +
                    '<div class="simplebox-content"><p>Content...</p></div>' +
                '</div>',

            editables: {
                title: {
                    selector: '.simplebox-title',
                    allowedContent: 'br strong em'
                },
                content: {
                    selector: '.simplebox-content',
                    allowedContent: 'p br ul ol li strong em'
                }
            },

            allowedContent:
                'div(!simplebox); div(!simplebox-content); h2(!simplebox-title)',

            requiredContent: 'div(simplebox)',

            upcast: function( element ) {
                return element.name == 'div' && element.hasClass( 'simplebox' );
            }
        } );
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to place a text/html at top, you can create a widget with an empty template. And, to locate a text/html at the beginning of a content, you need to add the following code in the init function of a widget.

```
editor.on('afterCommandExec', function (event) {
    var template = '<div class="simplebox1">' +
        '<h2 class="simplebox1-title">Title</h2>' +
        '<div class="simplebox1-content"><p>Content...</p></div>' +
        '</div>' 
    editor.setData(template + editor.getData())
})
```

For "at the very bottom", the logic is same.

To place a text/html in between paragraph 1 and 2, you need to divide the content of ckeditor into two parts by your criteria.

```
editor.setData(content_part1 + template + content_part2)
```

The whole code of two widgets (at top & at the very bottom):

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('simplebox', {
    requires: 'widget',

    icons: 'simplebox',

    init: function (editor) {
        editor.widgets.add('simplebox', {

            button: 'Create a simple box at top',

            template:
                '',

            editables: {
                title: {
                    selector: '.simplebox-title',
                    allowedContent: 'br strong em'
                },
                content: {
                    selector: '.simplebox-content',
                    allowedContent: 'p br ul ol li strong em'
                }
            },

            allowedContent:
                'div(!simplebox); div(!simplebox-content); h2(!simplebox-title)',

            requiredContent: 'div(simplebox)',

            upcast: function (element) {
                return element.name == 'div' && element.hasClass('simplebox');
            }
        });

        editor.on('afterCommandExec', function (event) {
            var template = '<div class="simplebox1">' +
                '<h2 class="simplebox1-title">Title</h2>' +
                '<div class="simplebox1-content"><p>Content...</p></div>' +
                '</div>' 
            editor.setData(template + editor.getData())
        })
    }
});

CKEDITOR.plugins.add('simplebox1', {
    requires: 'widget',

    icons: 'simplebox1',

    init: function (editor) {
        editor.widgets.add('simplebox1', {

            button: 'Create a simple box at very bottom',

            template:
                '',

            editables: {
                title: {
                    selector: '.simplebox1-title',
                    allowedContent: 'br strong em'
                },
                content: {
                    selector: '.simplebox1-content',
                    allowedContent: 'p br ul ol li strong em'
                }
            },

            allowedContent:
                'div(!simplebox1); div(!simplebox1-content); h2(!simplebox1-title)',

            requiredContent: 'div(simplebox1)',

            upcast: function (element) {
                return element.name == 'div' && element.hasClass('simplebox1');
            }
        });

        editor.on('afterCommandExec', function (event) {
            var template = '<div class="simplebox1">' +
                '<h2 class="simplebox1-title">Title</h2>' +
                '<div class="simplebox1-content"><p>Content...</p></div>' +
                '</div>' 
            editor.setData(editor.getData() + template)
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Your logic is not correct. The text from widget is going to be place at the current position of caret. you can try here  https://jsfiddle.net/radek/Lkac809m/59/

Comment: It works. I tried it. Did you try it?

Comment: I tried so many times. Run my jsfiddle click somewhere in the editor and then clik the button. the inserted text is going to be placed where you clicked last time. Not at the beginning